# notificacion de bootstrap-notify encima de modal

Tags: bootstrap

saludos a todos!.
lo que intento hacer es que en el momento que un modal este abierto y se ejecute una notificación de bootstrap-notify aparezca como debe ser , lo que me esta sucediendo es que me la esta poniendo detrás del modal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se puede ver en la imagen la notificación si se ejecuta pero esta detrás del modal quisiera saber si alguien me podría ayudar para que aparezca normal

Comment: Nos compartes tu código?

Comment: Por otro lado, la idea principal de un modal es que este por encima de todo, incluso las notificaciones. Lo que pudiera recomendar es poner el alert 'dentro' del modal, aunque depende de que es lo que se está buscando. Pero es una sugerencia.

Comment: Concuerdo con @KodiakMx, el modal debería estar siempre con el nivel de `z-index` mayor. Mira esta información al respecto: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/sassy-z-index-management-for-complex-layouts/

Comment: muchas gracias por los comentarios y si estaba pensando en cambiar el tipo de notificacion porque creo que las de bootstrap-notify.js no me lo permite y segun no he encontrado alguien que lo haya hecho, lounico seria pintar un div con la clase alert

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes solucionar cambiando la clase ".modal-backdrop" de Bootstrap y modificando z-index con un valor de 1030 (mayor que el del modal):

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 1030;
}
```